# nodes can't run on macos after migration from 2.0 to 3.0 in Corda

Tags: corda

After migrating our nodes on corda from 2.0 to 3.0, the nodes running on our mac os show error info as shown belo

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5006
java.lang.NullPointerException
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase$ClassEntry.equals(MethodDatabase.java:557)
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.recordSuspendableMethods(MethodDatabase.java:265)
...
I> Using policy access restrictor classpath:/jolokia-access.xml
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF en5: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF utun0: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF awdl0: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF en5: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF utun0: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF awdl0: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF en5: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF utun0: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF awdl0: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF en5: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF utun0: Can't assign requested address
I> Cannot join multicast group on NIF awdl0: Can't assign requested address
Jolokia: Agent started with URL http://127.0.0.1:7006/jolokia/
This Corda-specific web server is deprecated and will be removed in future.
Please switch to a regular web framework like Spring, J2EE or Play Framework.
```

Have found this is a bug in corda on this link, which has been fixed: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-1155, but not sure when and which version the fix will be released?

Comment: When redeploying the nodes, did you use 'clean'? i.e. did the old persistence file and artemis folder get deleted

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do a clean build when redeploying the node, either by:

- Using the Gradle `clean` flag (e.g. `gradlew clean deployNodes`)
- Deleting the `build` folder